# Use only today's session's data; when looking 2 bars back [2] do not include first two bars inorder to not retrieve yesterday's data

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Writing a gap indicator that will plot a box between a bar’s low and bar[2] high, and bar high and bar[2] low if there is a gap.
I do not want to do this for the first 2 bars of the session because the low/high of bar[2] the script grabs is from yesterday.

```
//@version=5
indicator("gaps test", "Gaps test", overlay = true, max_boxes_count = 500)

blGap = low > high[2]
brGap = high < low[2]
bar1  = session.isfirstbar_regular

if blGap and not session.isfirstbar_regular
    gapBox = box.new(left = bar_index[2],
     top = high[2], 
     right = bar_index, 
     bottom = low,
     border_color = color.lime, 
     border_width = 2, 
     border_style = line.style_dotted, 
     bgcolor = na)

if brGap and not session.isfirstbar_regular
    gapBox = box.new(left = bar_index[2],
     top = low[2], 
     right = bar_index, 
     bottom = high,
     border_color = color.red, 
     border_width = 2, 
     border_style = line.style_dotted, 
     bgcolor = na)
```

Found a way to exclude the first bar of session using “not session.isfirst_regular”. How can I exclude the second bar of the session? Or how can I exclude data from yesterday’s session when the indicator looks at bar[2]?

Answer (score 0):

The `time()` function allows you to check the open time of any particular bar, AND the open time of a higher-timeframe bar that the current bar is included in. Using it, you can check that the open time of the "1D" bar is the same for the current bar and for the one 2 bars ago, which means that they both are a part of the same daily candle. Here's how that would look:

```
//@version=5
indicator("gaps test", "Gaps test", overlay = true, max_boxes_count = 500)

blGap = low > high[2]
brGap = high < low[2]
// True when the current bar and the [2] bar are a part of the same daily session
bar2 = time("1D") == time("1D")[2]

if blGap and bar2
    gapBox = box.new(left = bar_index[2],
     top = high[2], 
     right = bar_index, 
     bottom = low,
     border_color = color.lime, 
     border_width = 2, 
     border_style = line.style_dotted, 
     bgcolor = na)

if brGap and bar2
    gapBox = box.new(left = bar_index[2],
     top = low[2], 
     right = bar_index, 
     bottom = high,
     border_color = color.red, 
     border_width = 2, 
     border_style = line.style_dotted, 
     bgcolor = na)
```